# BigQuery console api "Cannot start a job without a project id"

Tags: project, google-bigquery

I can call a sql on big query browser tool and I installed the bq tool on centos and register it now I can able connect bigdata and show the dataset or get the table data with head method but when i call the quert from bq tool I got "*BigQuery error in query operation: Cannot start a job without a project id.*" I searched it on google but nothing found helpful.

Does anyone run a select query via "*This is BigQuery CLI v2.0.1*"

BigQuery> ls

```
   projectId     friendlyName  
 -------------- -------------- 
  XXXX
```

**API Project**

```
BigQuery> show publicdata:samples.shakespeare   
Table publicdata:samples.shakespeare


   Last modified                  Schema                 Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration  
 ----------------- ------------------------------------ ------------ ------------- ------------ 
  02 May 02:47:25   |- word: string (required)           164656       6432064                   
                    |- word_count: integer (required)                                           
                    |- corpus: string (required)                                                
                    |- corpus_date: integer (required)
```

---

```
BigQuery> query "SELECT  title FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] LIMIT 10 "
BigQuery error in query operation: Cannot start a job without a project id.
```

---

Answer (score 3):

In order to run a query, you need to provide a project id, which is the project that gets billed for the query (there is a free quota of 25GB/month, but we still need a project to attribute the usage to). You can specify a project either with the --project_id flag or by setting a default project by running `gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID`. See the docs for bq and especially the 'Working with projects' section [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/cli_tool#projects).

Also it sounds like you may have an old version of bq. The most recent can be downloaded here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/